# How to sort the entire gridview rows by the datetime column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- There's a gridview on my asp page and sqldatasource to bind the data
  table info to gridview.
- I have 6 columns:
- First column is called ID : type : int, increment by one , primary
  key.
- The other columns are name,age etc..
- The last column is called Added : type : datetime .

I need to add a button or dropdownlist doesn't matter where I can sort the entire gridview rows by the DateTime Column.

Comment: On a side note, you really should take the above comment into consideration.  Give that [blog post](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) a read through before the next time you ask a question on here.  Try to include the details of your problem, as well as what, specifically you've tried and why you think it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an `SQLDataSource` with the `Gridview` already, I would say using the [AllowSorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx) property of the GridView (`AllowSorting="True"` in your markup) would be your easiest bet.  This will auto-generate buttons that let you sort by any column you like.

For example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="True">
```

A second option would be to do the sorting in your datasource.  You could just change the `SelectCommand` in your `SQLDataSource` to end with "`ORDER BY Added DESC`."  This would be ideal if you do not want the sorting to be a dynamic, user-prompted event, but just a static, default sorting of the `GridView` that does not change.

For example:

```
<asp:SQLDataSource ID="SQLDataSource1"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Name, Age, Column4, Column5, Added FROM yourTable ORDER BY Added DESC">
```